# Call function automatically inside other functions

Tags: javascript

I currently have a function which I call at the end in several other functions. Instead of writing it like this:

```
function foo(){

    baz();
}

function bar(){

    baz();
}

function baz(){

}
```

Is there any way to make `baz()` run automatically when calling the funcions? Perhaps by modifying the prototype of the other functions and add it as an IIFE? Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think something exists out of box, but you can fake it somehow. Try this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622639/how-do-i-create-a-javascript-listener-function-that-will-perform-an-action-when)

Comment: There's no way standard function ending method/event for such I believe. Though not very clean, you can replace those function references with wrappers that call the old functions. http://jsfiddle.net/L2uWt/

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yeah, I actually had a similar idea myself. But just as you said, it's not very clean. So I would say that it's not worth sacrificing the readability. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Yes, what you have currently is the most readable and clean way imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like "Template method" design pattern. If so, try this:

```
function inherit(proto) {
    var F = function() { };
    F.prototype = proto;
    return new F();
}

var template = {
    process: function() {
        this.mainfunction();
        this.baz();
    }
    baz:function(){

    }
};

(function run() {
    var foo = inherit(template);
    foo.mainfunction = function(){
    }
    foo.process();

    var bar = inherit(template);
    bar.mainfunction = function(){
    }
    bar.process();
}())
```

Comment: Even though this is correct, I think I'll stick to my original example, due to readability. Thanks

Comment: Why so complicated? `function wrap(f) { return function() { f(); baz(); }; }` and then `foo = wrap(foo); bar = wrap(bar);`